# Sparklyr - Unable to copy data.frames into Spark using copy_to

Tags: r, apache-spark, sparklyr

I'm trying to copy a big `dataframe` (around 5.8 million records) into Spark using Sparklyr's function `copy_to`.

First, when loading the data using `fread` (`data.table`), and applying the `copy_to` function, I got the following output error:

> Error in as.data.frame.default(x[[i]], optional = TRUE) : 
>         cannot coerce class ""integer64"" to a data.frame

Then, I changed the only two columns of type `integer64` into `character`, then applied the `as.data.frame` (it's a `data.table`, since I used `fread`) into all data.

Using `copy_to` again, it takes a long time before and after a progress bar shows up, but the following result is returned:

> Error in invoke_method.spark_shell_connection(sc, TRUE, class, method,  : 
>         No status is returned. Spark R backend might have failed.

No data is copied into Spark.

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 4):

I've run into this. Unfortunately copying dataframes from memory into Sparklyr just isn't the best way to import larger data. It works better through-and-through when I save my dataframe to disk as a `.csv` then read that into Spark directly.

For peak performance these best thing is to save it into parquet format on disk and read for that. Because Spark works using DAGs, if you have a more efficient on-disk data format for Spark to conduct operations on, your entire Spark operation will be faster when you hit collect, insert or whathaveyou.